# how to pass default component to child components using BrowserRouter, Switch and Route of react-router-dom@5.2.0 and react@17?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I made one admin default layout and wanted to use this component into every admin route component, but there is issue that my react version is 17 and react-router-dom version is 5.2.0, so this reason (may be i am wrong, because i am beginner) i haven't option to use like 'Outlet' (react-router-dom@6+). Please guide me to pass like :

(Route.js)

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Routes>
  <Route path="/admin/dashboard" element={AdminDefaultLayout}>
   <Route path="/admin/dashboard" element={Dashboard} />
   <Route path="/admin/category" element={Category} />
  </Route>
 </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

(AdminDefaultLayout.jsx)

```
<>
<div className="container">
 <Header />
 <Sidebar />
 <main>
  <Outlet />
 </main>
 <Footer />
</div>
</>
```

this is my package.json file

```
{
 "name": "magicbox",
 "version": "1.3.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "google-map-react": "^1.1.7",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "lax.js": "^1.2.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-accessible-accordion": "^3.3.4",
    "react-countup": "^4.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.2.8",
    "react-owl-carousel3": "^2.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.51.0"
  },
}
```

and this is my route.jsx file

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import HomeFour from "./components/pages/HomeFour";
import Login from "./components/pages/Login";

import AdminDefaultLayout from "./components/AdminDefaultLayout";
import Dashboard from "./components/pages/admin/Dashboard";

const renderNavigation = () => {
  if (!(window.location.pathname === '/login' || 
        window.location.pathname === '/signup' || 
        window.location.pathname === '/coming-soon' || 
        window.location.pathname === '/error-404' || 
        window.location.pathname === '/admin/dashboard'|| 
        window.location.pathname === '/admin/category')
    ) {
        return <Navigation />;
      }
}

const AppRouter = () => {
 const existToken = localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
 return (
  <>
    { existToken ? 
      (
       <Router>
        <Switch>
         <Route path="/admin/dashboard" render={(props) => <AdminDefaultLayout><Dashboard {...props} /></AdminDefaultLayout>}/>
        </Switch>
       </Router>
      ) : (
       <Router>
       {renderNavigation()}
        <Switch>
         <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
         <Route path="/" exact component={HomeFour} />
        </Switch>
       </Router>
       ) 
    }
   </>
  )
}

export default AppRouter;
```

(AdminDefaultLayout.jsx)

```
<>
 <div className="container">
  <Header />
  <Sidebar />
  <main>
    <Switch></Switch>
  </main>
  <Footer />
 </div>
</>
```

so, after doing this, only AdminDefaultLayout component is seen in page, no Dashboard component seen, please guide me. thanks for the help.

```
updated: there is not react-router found in my package.json file, i am apologized for wrong information, this is my first question so, my query is not in formatted too. but i got the solution after research on it. i am updating the answer, please see below and thanks for guide me @Drew Reese.
```

Comment: What version of React-Router are you trying to use. It's unclear since you've include code syntax from both v5 and v6. Please also [edit] the post to include formatted and readable code snippets.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your suggestion, i got my answer, i am updating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sometimes spend in research i got my solution from this reference link, [layouts in react-router](https://medium.com/@henev/simple-guide-for-layouts-in-react-router-e32b26c12cee)

In react 17 and react-router-dom@5.2.0 we can do this as given below:

in Routes.jsx file

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import HomeFour from "./components/pages/HomeFour";
import Login from "./components/pages/Login";

import AdminDefaultLayout from "./components/AdminDefaultLayout";
import Dashboard from "./components/pages/admin/Dashboard";
import ProtectedRoute from "./ProtectedRoute";

const renderNavigation = () => {
  if (!(window.location.pathname === '/login' || 
        window.location.pathname === '/signup' || 
        window.location.pathname === '/coming-soon' || 
        window.location.pathname === '/error-404' || 
        window.location.pathname === '/admin/dashboard'|| 
        window.location.pathname === '/admin/category')
    ) {
        return <Navigation />;
      }
}

const AppRouter = () => {
 const existToken = localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
 return (
  <>
    { existToken ? 
      (
       <Router>
        <Switch>
         <ProtectedRoute path="/admin/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} layout={AdminDefaultLayout} />
        </Switch>
       </Router>
      ) : (
       <Router>
       {renderNavigation()}
        <Switch>
         <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
         <Route path="/" exact component={HomeFour} />
        </Switch>
       </Router>
       ) 
    }
   </>
  )
}

export default AppRouter;
```

i made ProtectedRoute component to set 'AdminDefaultLayout' for admin routes, as given below code:

in ProtectedRoute.jsx file

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, layout: Layout, ...rest}) => {
    const existToken = localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');

    return (
        <>
            <Route {...rest} render = {(props) => existToken ? ( <Layout {...props} > <Component key={props.location.key} {...props} /> </Layout>) : (<Redirect to="/login" />)} />
        </>
    );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

after this in AdminDefaultLayout i passed children object into it, to show that default layout in particular admin pages/components which is given below:

in AdminDefaultLayout.jsx file

```
const AdminDefaultLayout = ({children}) => {
 return (
  <>
   <div className="container">
    <Header />
    <Sidebar />
    <main>
     {children}
    </main>
    <Footer />
   </div>
  </>
 );
};

export default AdminDefaultLayout;
```

and this is resolved my issue where i was stuck.
thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).